# AngularJs - Best-Practices on adding an active class on click (ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to add an active class on click in a list, i tried the following code, but it adds the active class on all my items :/ :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="filters in filter"  ng-click="select(item)" ng-class="{sel: item == selected}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filters.time}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Js :**

```
  var filters = [
            {
                'filterId': 1,
                'time': 'last 24 hours',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 2,
                'time': 'all',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 3,
                'time': 'last hour',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 4,
                'time': 'today',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 5,
                'time': 'yersteday',
            }
        ]; 


function selectFilter($scope) {

    $scope.items = ['filters'];
    $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];

    $scope.select= function(item) {
       $scope.selected = item; 
    };

}
```

Please, give me some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The best solution would be to target it via angulars `$index` which is the objects index/position in the array;

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{sel: $index == selected}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filter.time}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS/Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.controller('selectFilter', function($scope) {
var filters = [
            {
                'filterId': 1,
                'time': 'last 24 hours',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 2,
                'time': 'all',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 3,
                'time': 'last hour',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 4,
                'time': 'today',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 5,
                'time': 'yersteday',
            }
        ]; 

    $scope.filters = filters;
    $scope.selected = 0;

    $scope.select= function(index) {
       $scope.selected = index; 
    };
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/3G7Kd/)**

Comment: I'm trying to understand how it works, but i don't realize one thing, how you can change the style of a single element in the ng-click rather than change the style of everyone?

Comment: The click event is performed on one LI at a time and it's targeted by it's $index. So if you click on the first LI the index would be 0 and that's how it targets it. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes ok, but it's the expression in the ng-class that's not so clear to me, essentially is it a boolean and when it's true it gain the class sel?

Comment: Uep, so if the result from the expression on the `ng-class` directive is `true` then it sets the class `sel` on the LI and if not, it doesn't set it.

Comment: I wonder why this works: http://jsfiddle.net/f0mcLrxv/ (call function) but this not: http://jsfiddle.net/rseme7qn/ (set selected directly)

Comment: @CoperNick, they seem to be doing the exact same thing. Am I missing something. Oversight on my part perhaps? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Using `$scope.selected = 0;` will select the first item. You may have a use case where you do not want anything to be selected by default. In this case, instead of using `$scope.selected = 0;`, use `$scope.selected = -1;`. This will ensure that none of the items are selected by default.

Comment: Hey i gotta ask something. I am applying the same logic but not making any controller but managing the variable in html with ng-init. Let me know what i am doing wrong.

<ul ng-init="selected = -1">
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="selected = $index" ng-class="{sel: $index == selected}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filter.time}}
        </li>
    </ul>
http://jsfiddle.net/virendra656/009kxn78/3/

Comment: please some add how to change class when value is not equals $index

Answer (score 9):

Slow to answer, here is what I got ( might add a little more )

**WORKING DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/WVY7L/

**TEMPLATE**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" 
       ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{active: $index===selectedIndex}">
        <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
        {{filter.time}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.filters = [
        { filterId: 1, time: 'last 24 hours'},
        { filterId: 2, time: 'all' },
        { filterId: 3, time: 'last hour'},
        { filterId: 4, time: 'today' },
        { filterId: 5, time: 'yersteday'}
    ]; 
$scope.selectedIndex = 0; /* first one set active by default */
$scope.select= function(i) {
  $scope.selectedIndex=i;
};
```

- worth a mention that in the data you have trailing comma that should not be there.

  ```
   { filterId: 1, time: 'last 24 hours'**,**}
  ```

The rest was ensuring your controller was being passed the array number

```
ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{active: $index===selectedIndex}"
```

and being able to save that array number `selectedIndex` for use in your template

```
$scope.selectedIndex
```

**ng-class syntax**

```
    {active: $index===selectedIndex}
```

Translates to add class with name of 'active' when the '$index' is equal to the 'selectedIndex'

Comment: great stuff, it is actually the same method as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm well late to the party, but this is the most reusable pattern, and it will save you re-writing the same function every time.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="setActive(item, list)" ng-class="{active: item.active}"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.list = [{}, {}];

$scope.setActive = function(item, list){
  list.some(function(item){
    if(item.active){
      return item.active = false;
    }
  });
  item.active = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Test on the ID of the selected item :

```
<div class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in filters"  ng-click="select(item)" ng-class="{sel: item.filterId == selected.filterId}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filters.time}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var filters = [
            {
                'filterId': 1,
                'time': 'last 24 hours',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 2,
                'time': 'all',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 3,
                'time': 'last hour',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 4,
                'time': 'today',
            },
            {
                'filterId': 5,
                'time': 'yersteday',
            }
        ]; 
    function selectFilter($scope) {

        $scope.filters = filters;
        $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];

        $scope.select= function(item) {
           $scope.selected = item; 
        };

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i think the solution above is better, also thanks for your help

Comment: sorry i did not test the code, but what i wanted to point out here is that you must test on the attribute value ( item.filterId == selected.filterId ) instead of ( item == selected), anyway glad you found a solution.