# How to set active class on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I have this:

```
<div class="account-item">
    <div class="account-heading" ng-class="active">
        <h4 class="account-title">
            <a href="#/Messages"  onclick="SetActiveAccountHeading(this);">
            7.    @Translate("SYSTEM_MESSAGES")</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="account-item">
       <div class="account-heading" ng-class="active">
           <h4 class="account-title">
              <a href="#/Info"  onclick="SetActiveAccountHeading(this);">
              7.    @Translate("SYSTEM_INFO")</a>
           </h4>
      </div>
   </div>
```

In angular i have this:

```
$scope.active = "active";
```

but how can i change this on click so if user click on menu once it would be active if again click it would be NOT active?

Comment: for u http://plnkr.co/edit/nbMNSSMsWomoFJZi4XZd?p=preview :)

Comment: what if i have more menus? then every will be selected on click am i right?

Comment: how can i change that so if i have multiple menus that selected just that one that i clicked?? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81158/discussion-between-none-and-k-toress).

Comment: @None Try my answer below with cleaner code and working jsfiddle link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975718/how-to-set-active-class-on-ng-click/30975988#30975988

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Ok say you have multiple menu items and you want to toggle the class according to click,

you can create a array **in the controller** which represents the menu items as,

```
$scope.menuItems = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About', 'Other'];
```

assign the default selected ,menu item

```
$scope.activeMenu = $scope.menuItems[0];
```

create a function to assign the selected Menu value, this function will assign the `$scope.activeMenu` a last selected menu item.

```
 $scope.setActive = function(menuItem) {
    $scope.activeMenu = menuItem
 }
```

in **HTML**

loop through the `menuItems` array and create the menu.

in the `ng-class` check last clicked menu item is equal to item in the repeat.

if click on the menu then call `setActive()` function in the controller and pass the menu item name as an argument.

```
<div class="account-item" ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>
   <div class="account-heading" ng-class="{active : activeMenu === item}">
      <h4 class="account-title">
        <a href="#/Messages" ng-click="setActive(item)"> {{ item }}</a>
      </h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TtQNQXOLggs1bsYKNJvx?p=preview)

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dBbQzbDWlcEznrsSwFQJ?p=preview) without `ng-repeat`

Comment: How would you do this if instead of menu items being a list of strings, it were a list of objects? AFAIK you can't do a `===` compare on objects.

Comment: Also- can you explain what this syntax is? `ng-class="{active : activeMenu === item}"`

Comment: Hmmm this answer here is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902583/angularjs-best-practices-on-adding-an-active-class-on-click-ng-repeat

Answer (score 11):

This is what you need.

```
<div class="account-item" ng-init="active = true">
  <div class="account-heading" ng-class="{'active': active === true}" ng-click="active = !active">
    <h4 class="account-title">
        <a href="#/Messages">7.    @Translate("SYSTEM_MESSAGES")</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

No other scripting. +1 if it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Angular4:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>

<a [routerLink]="['calendar']" routerLinkActive="active">
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [**ui-router**] you not need to write anything just you have add this **ui-sref-active="active-menu"** property in your tag which you want to active after click/navigate.

Comment: how i can add this and where ?

Comment: <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active-menu">Home</a>

Answer (score 2):

For cleaner code try this:

```
<div class="account-item" ng-init="active = true">
  <div class="account-heading" ng-class="{'active': active}">
    <h4 class="account-title">
        <a href="#/Messages" ng-click="active = !active">7. @Translate("SYSTEM_MESSAGES")</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can remove the onclick event **SetActiveAccountHeading(this);**.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/52or6fg1/2/)**.


You can view the result in the **developer's console**.

Hope it helps.