# How to add the `active` class on click of `li` element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS. I need to know how to handle this scenario using it.

I have an array with values. I am using `ng-repeat` to iterate the array and it works fine. My requirement is how to add a class(`active`) to **first** child of `ul` and whenever user clicks, the clicked element should get the `active` class and **remove the** `active` **class** from the rest of the `li` elements.

I've done that in JQuery very easily like:

```
$('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
```

But how to achieve the same here?

My code :

**JavaScript Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("main", function ($scope) {

  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];

  $scope.activate = function (item) {

    //how to active this item?

    //onload how to add class on first li?

  }

})
```

**HTML**

```
 <ul>

    <li ng-click="activate(item)" ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
    </li>

  </ul>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOSssomewrb69g8gBBcb?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs - Best-Practices on adding an active class on click (ng-repeat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902583/angularjs-best-practices-on-adding-an-active-class-on-click-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this. Store the current active item in your controller and apply a class to it if it is the one.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li 
        ng-click="activate(item)" 
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-class="{'active': item == active}">{{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS Controller**

```
$scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.active = items[0]; // for onload first element active
$scope.activate = function (item) {
    $scope.active = item;
}
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VNczEPuiT7vlLiEB7wLz?p=preview)

Comment: But on load the first element hasn't have the active class here

Comment: Yes, agree. and I need to show some aditional elements to show, when the `li` is active. how to do that? here is the demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/kF5s39eKjqyhC6NE7O9G?p=preview

Comment: Try to limit to 1 question per thread. It is much easier for users then searching the topic / answer.