# give active class onclick in ngFor angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-class, ngfor

Hi I have unordered list and all of them have active class. I want to toggle active class when clicked to any list item. My code is like this

```
<ul class="sub_modules">
  <li *ngFor="let subModule of subModules" class="active">
    <a>{{ subModule.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do something like:

```xml
<ul class="sub_modules">
  <li (click)="activateClass(subModule)"
      *ngFor="let subModule of subModules"
      [ngClass]="{'active': subModule.active}">
    <a>{{ subModule.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On The component

```js
activateClass(subModule){
  subModule.active = !subModule.active;    
}
```

On the Ng class the first property is the class you wanna add and the second is the condition;

Comment: Thank You @Eduardo .. This is what I want but all list items should have already active class.. so how can I do that?

Comment: you can do an map to the array.

array.map(obj = > {
obj.active=false;
return obj;
})

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it with obj.active=true... This is what I want) it works perfectly)

Answer (score 44):

just make an index property. use `let i = index` to set the index using (click) event. Then check if `selectedIndex === i` if yes the set class "active" to true

```xml
<ul class="sub_modules">
  <li *ngFor="let subModule of subModules; let i = index" 
      [class.active]="selectedIndex === i" 
      (click)="setIndex(i)">
    <a>{{ subModule.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then on typescript file: just set selectedIndex.

```
export class ClassName {
   selectedIndex: number = null;

   setIndex(index: number) {
      selectedIndex = index;
   }
}
```

Comment: You have an error in you HTML block. `[class.active]='sIndex === i` instead of `[class.active]='selectedIndex === i`. Otherwise, good answer :-)

Comment: It's not toggling

Comment: Was looking for a simple solution and found this... thanks. I always like to use Angular's shorthand template methods before reverting to component logic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find your answer here: [[AngularJs - Best-Practices on adding an active class on click (ng-repeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902583/angularjs-best-practices-on-adding-an-active-class-on-click-ng-repeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902583/angularjs-best-practices-on-adding-an-active-class-on-click-ng-repeat)

You can target and apply CSS to an item/object through Angular's `$index`. The post explains and demonstrates the logic better than I can.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add & clarify a possible misconception:

- You can only add *classes* via via `[ngClass]`.
- You can NOT add *selectors* like the `:active` [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

```html
<li [ngClass]="{'active': isActive === true}">
```

Mind the difference:

```css
.li.active {
  // This works! :)
}

.li:active {
  // This doesn't work! :(
}
```

It might be obvious for some, but took me ~15 minutes of trial & error to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
the loop
<div *ngFor="let item of divs; let i = index">
    <app-cool [index]="i"></app-cool>
</div>

the <app-cool></app-cool> html  
<div (click)="setActive()"  [class.active]="isActive()">

</div> 

the <app-cool></app-cool> ts
static activeIndex = -1;

@Input() index: number = -1;
    
public setActive(): void{
    ThisClass.activeIndex = this.index;
}

public isActive(): boolean{
    return ThisClass.activeIndex === this.index;
}
```