# Can't assign [ngClass] to Angular components generated by *ngFor loop

Tags: css, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to follow [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287475/1525840) showing how to bind a class *active* to a component when it's clicked. When I execute the code based on the markup below

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus;"
     [id]="menu.id"
     (click)="onClick($event,menu.link)"
     [ngClass]="'active':menu.active"
     class="navigator">
  {{menu.title}}
</div>
```

I get the following error. NB - there's *onClick(...)* method in the component and at the moment I commented out all its contents. The error seems to be purely related to the markup (unless I need to declare something extra in the component, like an array or such). At least as far I've seen the examples while googlearching this issue.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 9 in ['active':menu.active] in ng:///AppModule/NavigatorComponent.html@11:9 ("
>            [id]="menu.id"
>            (click)="onClick($event,menu.link)"
>            [ERROR ->][ngClass]="'active':menu.active"
>            class="navigator">
>         {{menu.title}}
>   "): ng:///AppModule/NavigatorComponent.html@11:9

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'active':menu.active` isn't a valid expression.

User either the object literal syntax

```
[ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}"
```

or the string syntax

```
[ngClass]="menu.active ? 'active' : null"
```

or

```
[class.active]="menu.active"
```

Answer (score 1):

An other approach in this case,  could be using [class] property, because it could be more concise, as pointed out by @Günter Zöchbauer:

```
 <div *ngFor="let menu of menus;"
     [id]="menu.id"
     (click)="onClick($event,menu.link)"
     [class.active]="menu.active"
     class="navigator">
  {{menu.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... How doe sit relate to `[ngClass]`? Are we talking just different syntaxes or a totally different approach?

Comment: It has the same effect but it is more concise than using `ngClass`. `ngClass` is for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, must have said, an other approach :) easier to write and shorter?

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}"
```

This is the correct syntax