# How to use [ngClass] in a *ngFor Angular component without a local index keeper?

Tags: css, angular, ngfor

I'm using the following markup to mark the clicked component as active.

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus;"
     (click)="onClick($event,menu.link)"
     [ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}">
  {{menu.title}}
</div>
```

The method handling the click is as follows.

```
onClick(target, link) {
  target.active = !target.active;
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { primary: [""], menus: [link] } }]);
}
```

It seems that the value of `target.active` goes from `undefined` to `true` to `false` to `true` etc. **but** the style doesn't get set. (I'm printing out the whole component to the console and can't see the addition of the class' name.)

**Question:** What am I missing in this approach?

NB, I know how to resolve it by approaching it from a different angle. I set up a local variable keeping the index and setting it [like shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45547427/1525840). The aim of my question is to learn to achieve the requested behavior in a more like-a-bossy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` here:

```
onClick(target, link) {
  target.active = !target.active;   <------------
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { primary: [""], menus: [link] } }]);
}
```

doesn't refer to `menu`, it refers to the event. But based on your `ngClass` directive:

```
[ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}">
```

You need to set `active` to `menu` variable and so it can be done like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus;"
     (click)="onClick(menu,menu.link)"
     [ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}">
  {{menu.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: This was an awesomely clear explanation. I'd +2 you but I can't. You're only getting +1 due to site's limitations. A quick follow up, as long as we're on like-a-bossy approaches. If I want the rest of the menu items to lose the *active* state upon one of them gaining it through this click - is there a neat trick for that too? Like emptying some array of holders of the bound components or something?

Comment: @AndyJ, thanks. `this.menus.forEach((m)=>m.active=false)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing something similar like this: `this.menus.forEach(_ => _.active = _ === target);` but I was hoping for even a smoother ride, like if one binding gets set, then the rest automagically lose the previous setting. Perhaps I'm over-thinking it. Your answer is more than enough. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the $event, send it the actual menu object. Like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus;"
     (click)="onClick(menu)"
     [ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}">
  {{menu.title}}
</div>
```

And in the component:

```
onClick(menu) {
  menu.active = !menu.active;
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { primary: [""], menus: [menu.link] } }]);
}
```