# How to use custom directives in html

Tags: angularjs

I have created one custom directive to add `active` class for clicked `li` in menu list based on url.

```
.directive('addActive', [function() {
    return{
        ...
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){

                pageUrl = location.pathname;
                $('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
                if (pageUrl) {
                    debugger
                    console.log($('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])'))
                    $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
                }
        }
    }
}]);
```

directive code defines that when a menu is clicked, `active` class should be added for `current url`.
how can I use this directive in html code?

Html:

```
 <div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
            <ul class="nav main-menu">
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="/employee/Home" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Home</span>
                    </a>                       
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="/documents/doc_details" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Documents</span>
                    </a>                       
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Pay &amp; Benifits</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="ng-scope">
                            <a href="/pay/paymanagement" ng-click="tabName(child.name)" class="ng-binding">slips</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Please guys any help?

Comment: You should simply use ng-class on your component, instead of a new directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Above comment is right. If you still want to know how to use directives, have a look at the docs. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I aggre ng-class is the way to do here . What you should probably do is hold a list with boolean values for your <li> elements and onClick make its value true( this should be associated with a condition on ng-class). Also every time you click an element you should make false the rest of list first
also check this solution using $index 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902583/angularjs-best-practices-on-adding-an-active-class-on-click-ng-repeat

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe @D.Simon if I use `ng-click` in `li`, each click of list ,page will get refreshed.so `active` class cant be added.Am I right?

Comment: @PanosK you are correct but for li each click my page gets refreshed.Thats why am trying to do using current url.

Comment: @laz your condition on ng-class should be based on your current url so you probably want to keep this on a scope variable in your controller, using jquery addClass is definitely not the correct way to do this

Comment: @PanosK can you please give some sample code for my condition.please

Comment: ng-class="{'active': $location.path() == 'pathToAddActiveCondition' }"
not tested  but should work. Iwill make a plunkr when i find some time

Comment: @laz AngularJS is for Single Page Applications (SPA). Those shouldn't refresh, only render data (on $digest cycle for angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the most important information about your directive: the 'restrict' attribute indicates how should the directive can be used in your html. For instance: using retrict: 'E', means that your directive can be used as an html element

```html
<add-active></add-active>
```

But i guess that in you situation, your restrict value is 'A', and you should use it as an attribute:

```html
<div add-active></div>
```

for more info you can see the angularJS directive's documentation here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

but i agree with the folks above me that in this case, you probably just need to use ng-class (that is also a directive).

Comment: Simply can I add like this ? `<div id="sidebar-left" add-active>` Does it work?

Comment: yes, if your directive's restrict attribute is 'A' .

Answer (score -2):

I think Yaniv's answer is what you need.
But I suggest you try `ng-class`. 
In your code, you are trying to use the url so I think this might help you:
[How to highlight a current menu item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592472/how-to-highlight-a-current-menu-item)